# Local docker container cannot route to Azure database

Tags: azure, docker

Context:

Windows host (with up-to-date Docker For Windows).

Linux-based container running on said host.

MySQL database running on Azure (and not in a container).

When running the container it is impossible to ping the Azure database (let alone query it). The message indicates that it cannot find a route to {azure db IP}.
However I can easily access a database on my Windows host local network. I can also access the internet, for example to download ping tools on my container.

My Windows host can ping and query the Azure database.
I've tried messing with Docker ip configuration (in the visual application) as well as going into the container at run time and changing its ip address since Docker default address is in the same subnet as Azure.
I've even tried switching the virtual commutator on the hyper-v machine but Docker seems to recreate those configurations when restarting.

How can my container successfully route to an azure network?

Thank you for your advice and help.

Comment: How do you access the MySQL database inside the Docker container? use the FQDN of the database?

Comment: Yes I provide a full connection string to NHibernate (with login and password). Using the db FQDN I can translate the IP but not route towards this IP.

Comment: Docker does not set the route for you. You need to set it yourself. Two ways as I know, one is that use the IP of the database, another is that you can mount your local name server file into your container.